# Mock DBContext class which uses a stored procedure and SqlAdapter to fetch details using Nunit and Moq

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, nunit, moq, dbcontext

I need to Mock a DBContext class which in turn uses a Stored procedure & SqlAdapter to fetch result using Nunit and Moq . There is Unity Resolver IOC involved which takes care of DI .

```
    ---Web API Controller Class----

    IEmployee _employee;
    public Controller(IEmployee employee)
    {
      _employee = employee;
    }

    Route[employeedetails/get]
    [HttpPost]
    public EmployeeEntity Get(ParameterObject param)
    {
       return _employee.Get(param);
    }
    ----------------------------------

    Employee implements IEmployee :

    --- DataAccess Class which implements the interface----

    public class Employee : IEmployee 
    {
      public EmployeeContext _repository;
      public Employee(EmployeeContext repository)
      {
        _repository = repository;
      }

      public EmployeeEntity Get(ParameterObject param)
      {
         DataSet dataset= new DataSet();
         EmployeeEntity response = new EmployeeEntity();
         using(SqlConnection connection = 
          (SqlConnection)_repository.Database.Connection)
         {
          connection.Open()
          SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
          command.CommandText = "spGetEmployee";
          command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          -- Add Parameters using param object --
         using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
         {
           adapter.Fill(dataset);
           response = MapReponse(dataset);
         }
         connection.Close();
       }
      return response;
     }
     }
    -------------------------------------
    --------DBContext class -----------

    public partial class EmployeeContext : DbContext
    {
      public EmployeeContext() : base ("name=EmployeeContext")
      {
      }
    }
```

So I need to Mock the DB functionality using NUnit and Moq .. My code using Unity resolver . Please help I tried many ways . Nothing si working for me ....

Comment: Have you tried the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking?

Comment: Yes .But it doesn't  help me implement in my existing code ... :(

Comment: Ya I know Moq and Nunit doesn't have much knowledge base ... Hoping someone would help..